# Running executable files on Linux

Tags: linux, executable

I have made my Python script executable with `chmod +x` and now I can run it from the terminal with ./ prefix (./script_name).

What exactly does this prefix mean? Why is it needed to run an executable file?

Answer (score 3):

Like any other program, a shell is also a program which is waiting for input. Now when you type in `command1 arg1 arg2 ...` , the first thing a shell does is to try to identify `command1` from among the following:

1. a function (try `typeset -f` in Bash shell)
2. an in-built command (such as `type`)
3. a shell alias (try `alias` in Bash shell)
4. a file that can be executed

Now the question concerns the last point **a file that can be executed**. A Unix kernel will **need absolute path of an executable file** in `exec()` system call (see `man exec`).

To obtain the absolute path of a file, the shell first looks up the command in directories specified in **$PATH** variable.

So if you specify the relative path such as `../abc/command1` or `./command1` then Bash will be able to find that file and pass it to `exec()` system call.

If all the above four steps fail to locate the `command1` input to the shell, you will get:

```
$ command1
command1: command not found
```

However, if the file's absolute path is resolved, but it is not executable, you get:

```
$ command1
bash: ./command1: Permission denied
```

References:

- [How does the shell work](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/newbie/165104-how-does-shell-work.html#post784136)
- [How BASH Shell Command Search Sequence Works](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/an-example-how-shell-understand-which-program-to-run-part-ii.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the references, I will read it.

Comment: The first link is (effectively) broken: *"linuxforums.org is parked free, courtesy of GoDaddy.com."*

Answer (score 2):

It means the current directory and the script is in the current directory.

Comment: Please stop up-voting me! It is a trivial question and the answer is trivial

Answer (score 1):

The OS searches your `$PATH` when using a bare executable name (`foo` vs `./foo`).  In your case, the file may not reside on the path, so you need to tell the OS exactly where it is.  You do that by specifying the path to the executable.  That's what the `./` i saying: look for the executable in my current working directory.  It's called a "relative path", and they're handy for when the thing you want to reference is close to your current working directory.

Comment: SO if it was added in the $PATH,the ./ would not be needed?